# Issues with firebase authentication

Tags: html, firebase, forms, firebase-authentication

Hi there newbie here.

I created a simple login with html, css and js. Authentication is running on firebase, localhost training dummy. The problem I encountered is that as soon as I add  tags around my inputs and buttons the page just reloads on the button press. The "solution" is to remove the form tags and everything is running smoothly, but I have to admit that this does not satisfy my knowledge of semantics and stuff.

```
 <form id="userLogin" class="form-container">
            <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="email">

            <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" autocomplete="current-password">

            <button id="btnLogin">Log in</button>

            <button id="btnSignUp">Sign up</button>

            <button id="btnLogout">Log out</button>

            <button id="verify">Verify me</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing you're  tags.

You should either do:

```html
<input id='input' />
```

or this way:

```html
<input id='input' ></input>
```

Your final code should look like this:

```html
<form id="userLogin" class="form-container">
  <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="" autocomplete="email" />

  <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" autocomplete="current-password" />

  <button id="btnLogin">Log in</button>

  <button id="btnSignUp">Sign up</button>

  <button id="btnLogout">Log out</button>

  <button id="verify">Verify me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you John, I didn't see that! But my problem is still there. I guess it could be an issue with not stating an action in the form?

Comment: Sorry for that. I believe you missing a type='submit' inside of the button tag, that will make sure that the form is being submitted and not just pressing the button

Comment: Yes, in addition to that it was just not necessary to use the form I guess